# How to get the pixels fit the specified color in bitmap UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to find out all the pixels fit the specified color in bitmap.

For example, I want to find the positions(x, y) of the pixels these are color: `[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]`.

How to get this?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Comment: `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` returns, as the name says, PNG data, which is a **compressed** representation of the image. Accessing the pixels like in your code will not work.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to find the pixel position with color, not find color of the pixel from image.